# Mysql and Python on Mac

Tags: python, mysql, macos

I installed Mysqldb for python but when I run it, I get this error:

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg/_mysql.py:3: UserWarning: Module _mysql was already imported from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg/_mysql.pyc, but /Users/bb/Workspace/MySQL-python-1.2.3 is being added to sys.path
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    import _mysql
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/_mysql.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/_mysql.py", line 6, in __bootstrap__
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/bb/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg-tmp/_mysql.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/bb/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg-tmp/_mysql.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

Any idea on how to run MySQL with Python on MAC. I've spent the last 2 days working on it

Answer (score 0):

I got this same error when I downloaded the 32bit version instead of the 64bit version, Installing the 64bit version fixed it.